# How do i sum up the values of a particular sales Rep in a table

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

***This is the table:***

[image]

How can I sum up all Expr for sales rep "03"

When I use a calculator , The sum of `03` will be correct , and I have tried `sum(number-ordered * quoted_price)` But it goes ahead to add all salesrep's sales together

Comment: You need to `group by` sales rep and use `where` for particular reps only

Comment: In order to get a proper, accurate answer, please modify your question to include the raw data (not as an image), and expected outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the limited amount of data, I will have to provide you with a minimal answer.

Essentially what you are doing right now is that you are trying to get a sum of all of them.

You will need to use a `where` condition or `group by` to get only data of the the rep.